# Can be use condition in CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Building a Wordpress theme and I am not on the first page but on other pages content to have.

This is the site:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro

I turned off main site

```
 .masthead-fixed .site-main {
    margin-top: 48px;
    display:none;
```

For example ... if a user clicks on "Sample Page" I want #.masthead-fixed to be activate else...not be displayed.

It can do so in CSS?
What technology can I use?

It would help me a strong example to understand more clearly what to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your link returns a blank page, probably you have a php error. you cannot do it in css, I suggest javascript. your question is not clear enough

Comment: Are you trying to make the header dynamically change on click ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the generated HTML. Each page will have some unique classes on the `body` tag. For instance, the frontpage will have a `.home` class, and depending on template, your `body` tag will also have a template class, e.g. `.page-template-default`. Most importantly, though, is that each page will have a unique id, e.g. `.page-id-7`. You can easily use these to differentiate between specific pages in your CSS.

So look at the source code of your "Sample Page", find its id and adjust the CSS accordingly:

```
body.page-id-X .masthead-fixed .site-main {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to show only when you're not on the home page you can use the following PHP in your template file.

```
<?php if (!is_home() || !is_front_page()) { ?> 

<div id="something">This div and content will only show up if we're not on the front page</div> 

<?php } ?>
```

So here's a standard masthead found in header.php

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <div class="site-branding">
            <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
        <label for="menu" class="menu-label" onclick></label>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="off-canvas">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => '' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

Change the above code to this:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
  <?php if (!is_home() || !is_front_page()) { ?> <!-- PLACE THIS LINE ABOVE YOUR HEADER -->
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <div class="site-branding">
            <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
        <label for="menu" class="menu-label" onclick></label>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="off-canvas">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => '' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
 <?php } ?> <!-- PLACE THIS CODE AFTER THE HEADER -->
    <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

This will display your header on all pages except your home page.